# Install package in R: 'stdlib.h' file not found

Tags: r, package, installation, stdio

I am trying to install RMark from RStudio. I notice that one of the packages required could not be installed. It seems there are some issues with C. Can you help me?

```html
> install.packages('mvtnorm')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 159539 bytes (155 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 155 KB

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'mvtnorm' ...
** package 'mvtnorm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
In file included from C_FORTRAN_interface.c:8:
In file included from ./mvtnorm.h:2:
/anaconda3/lib/R/include/R.h:55:11: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
# include <stdlib.h> /* Not used by R itself, but widely assumed in packages */
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:160: C_FORTRAN_interface.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvtnorm'
* removing '/anaconda3/lib/R/library/mvtnorm'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'mvtnorm' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 '/private/var/folders/5m/lbpq3yj53n7clgx4r1fy6blr0000gn/T/RtmppNGt3S/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed R using conda (I guess, from the path) so install packages using [conda procedures](https://anaconda.org/r/r-mvtnorm) rather than `install.packages()`.

Answer (score 3):

If your trying to install a package that does not exist in the conda repo, you can also install the needed SDK headers for Mojave

`open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

[Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104296)